# Migrate from SQL server 2008 to 2012

Tags: sql-server, web-services, connection, oledb

I have successfully migrated all my databases from 2008 to 2012 and mapped the user to the specific databases.

My problem being is 2008 expired (hence why I got 2012) and I was using a web service to call/edit data in the tables.

When I run a web service function it just times out which suggests to me that it is still trying to talk to 2008.

I am using -

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

with connection -

```
OleDbConnection objConnection = null;
OleDbCommand objCmd = null;
String strConnection, strSQL;
strConnection = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NSN;User Id=userID;Password=password;Connect Timeout=300";
```

My question being, how can I tell the web service to point at SQL server 2012 now that I have migrated all the databases?

Comment: Are both of your SQL servers installed on the same computer?

Comment: I would recommend that you'd use the `SqlConnection` instead of the old `OleDbConnection`

Comment: Take a look in SQL Server configuration manager if you have more than one istance running? If you installed SQL 2012 while still having 2008 installed the chances are that 2012 is not a default instance and connection string would have to look like this: ...Data Source=.\INSTANCENAME;Initial Catalog...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your SQL Server 2008 has expired why dont you then remove the access for the user mentioned in your connection string to the SQL 2008 Db  or best make it offline. If the application fails then you know that it was still pointing to SQL2008.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your connection string to the following:

```
strConnection = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=.\<INSTANCENAME>;Initial Catalog=NSN;User Id=userID;Password=password;Connect Timeout=300";
```

Where  is the name of your SQL Server 2012 instance. It should be the same as you type in the 'Server name' in management studio login dialog.

The problem is that you are trying to connect to the default instance which is your SQL Server 2008 installation.